# Single redis instance with local redis connections via unix socket and remote via tcp. Possible?

Tags: redis

I have local Redis instance listening on Unix socket. Is it possible to allow remote connections to this Redis instance via TCP? Any solutions? Maybe some kind of proxying TCP <> Unix socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for a proxy of some kind, you can enable both socket and TCP listening in redis.conf like this:

```
port 6379
# bind 127.0.0.1

unixsocket /tmp/redis.sock
```

Having the `bind 127.0.0.1` commented out defaults to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: thank you! Very simple :) By the way, will this trick work with `memcached`?

Comment: @Kirzilla no, `memcached` is either socket or TCP